# Fail to vagrant up laravel homestead

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrnTJ.png)
By following the instruction at https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead,I had installed laravel homestead using vagrant 1.8.0 and Virtual box 5.1.10 on WIN7 yesterday. 
However the computer was power off accidently. When I restart the computer, I got these errors:

```
Administrator@L3L44LWAP6XZHHR MINGW64 ~/Homestead (master)

$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
   homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
   homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
   homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
   homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
   homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
   homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
   homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
Command: ["startvm", "75bdb497-9044-4c49-ab2d-5244eb234d6e", "--type", "headless                                                              "]
Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'homestead-7' has terminated
unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available
in 'C:\Users\Administrator\VirtualBox VMs\homestead-7\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'

VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine.
```

I tried to reinstall the virtual box and the vagrant, but it doesn't work to me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `vagrant reload` command will helpful for you.

Comment: I think the error might come from the virtual box~

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/homestead-virtualization-suddenly-gone?page=1

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a same type of problem and have solved the problem.
Oracle VM 5.1.12 is okay for me.
Sometimes antivirus/firewall applications are troubling to this kind of activities. So try to disable or remove antivirus app to check whether the problem will continue.

Answer (score 0):

The command "vagrant reload" solved for me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've  removed VirtualBox and installed the version 5.2.2

This has been fixed my problem.

But before the problem occurred, I'd upgraded the vagrant. I thought that your vagrant version is not suitable for your VirtualBox version. Please double check your versions.

Comment: while I was upgrading Vagrant, Vagrant installation give me a warning about  it